# mage folder got deleted accidently [ magento 1.9 ]

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I accidentally deleted mage folder. I don't have any backup of my project.[haven't done any changes to mage files ]

so my questions are

1] Is  there a way to retrieve that folder ?

2] can we use fresh mage folder of another magento installation ? if not Why?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done any changes yourself to the Mage core files (as is recommended) then there is no problem taking a fresh copy of the Magento 1.9 Mage directory.

When we deploy our Magento sites we always start off with a fresh Magento 1.9 and then add our customised files after that. It works like a charm as long as one has followed the guidelines of never changing `/app/code/core` and other core/base files.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have any backup, than there is no option to retrieve that folder. its better if you take backup time to time. magento default feature support backups.
also you need to copy the same version of magento `Mage`  folder. you can get all versions in magento official and in git hub.